# How to automate populating Python's class constructor?

Tags: macro, vimscript-python, text-generation

I've done some searching with various keywords, but unsuccessfully. Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker.

I'm new to VIM and to Python, and I'm learning both on the go as much as I can, but sometimes I hit a brick wall and land here. Though SE already answered most of my questions, hence this is my first one.

While I'm not sure if it's even possible (why am I the only junior Python programmer searching/asking for that?), I'd like to know for sure without learning the whole scripting language beforehand and discovering it's not.

To the point:

When I'm writing a new class in Python I have to write:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, ..., argn, namedarg1 = defaultvalue, namedarg2 = "default string value", namedarg3, ... namedargn):
    self.arg1 = arg1
    ...        
    self.argn = argn
    self.namedarg1 = namedarg1
    self.namedarg2 = namedarg2
    self.namedarg3 = namedarg3
    ...
    self.namedargn = namedargn
```

... which seems a terrible waste of time, especially once I've heard about vim macros, snippets, autocorrect, etc.

**What would be the best way to automate change from, let's say, this:**

```
Testclass(arg1, ..., argn, namedarg1 = defaultvalue, namedarg2 = "default string value", namedarg3, ... namedargn)
```

**to the first example I showed?** How would it work (i.e. *how do I use it*; bonus points for explaining how would the macro/script/snippet work)?

Comment: Here's what I'd do (because you'll learn more my doing): try to create a macro that works only for comma-separated arguments name. Then introduce the default values. Your macro should do something like: copy the argument name, type some text and past the argument name.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, but that's not what I'm looking for. I can do small macros, but that's not the point, I wanted a systemic solution, not to record a macro (probably failing at it a few dozen times) and run it n times over the constructor. Had I wanted to do that, I'd write a python script to do that instead of using vimscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), whose [git page](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) actually has a gif of it in action, doing almost exactly what I want (I guess I'm in for a bit of tweaking):

[image: ultisnips]

Thanks for the interest! Cheers.